# Harvard style; multiple works by same author - syntax of tex file

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

I want to create this kind of output in a hardvard style document (within the text).

...see Smith (1990, 1991a, 1991b) for further details...

In other styles i could write something like `\citep{smith1990,smith1991a,smith1991b}` but this gives me a `?` in harvard.

Changing bibliographystyle is not unfortunately an option. Can anyone advise whether this is actually possible/the correct syntax? [I can probably fake it using `\citeasyear*` and so on).]

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is citing these refs together? Have you tried citing them separatly - does this work?

Comment: If I cite them separately, I get: Smith (1990), Smith (1991a), Smith (1991b). It's the repetition of the name I hope to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages (and not loading the `harvard` package)? Doing so would allow you to keep using one of the bibliography style files distributed with the `harvard` package while being still being able to use the commands `\citet` and `\citep` provided by the `natbib` package. It would also give you better interactions with the `hyperref` package (should you be using it, of course). If you go this route, just be sure to blow away the `.aux` file.

Comment: Given the number of Harvard-specific commands like `\citeyear`, `\citeyear*` etc (and my familiarity with it), it's less work to fake it as mentioned than start messing with new packages and redoing/checking all commands (there are hundreds). The implication of the suggestions is that this is not something that harvard supports ... (can anyone say that for certain?) (And I'm not using hyperref as it will probably have to go through latex2rtf). I may do the necessary edits in the RTF but would rather have a 'perfect' pdf for the reviewer.

Comment: Without a MWE of your set up, this is very unlikely to get answered. Please edit one in.